# Android Skmaps - not works with sdk v.2.3

Tags: android, skmaps

I work on Skobbler maps with Android but wanting to move from version 2.1 to version 2.3 sdk I have a problem. I have no error and I see through the log that the application works as it should, but the background map no appears.

Have you ever had this problem?

The demo works fine but when I include my project nothing.

If you need my project is [here](http://dev.kinomap.com/dev/kinomap/SKMaps_2.3.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you follow these steps for [updating the SDK (2.X to 2.Y)](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec028)

- Replace SKMaps.zip
- Replace SKMaps.jar and SKMaps-docs.jar
- Replace allso libs from armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86

Make sure that both the framework library & the SkMaps.zip are updated to the 2.3 version (replace those in your project with the ones coming from the demo project zip). It could be an issue generated by an partial update & conflicting meta/resource files.

Comment: Yes, I follow these steps. I note also that my app doesn't pass by onSurfaceCreated.

Comment: An issue regarding your question has been filed internally and it's pending with the development team

Comment: Changes that need to be made to your demo project: 
1) Calling onResume() on the SKMapSurfaceView object in the right places (see differences from initial MainActivity.java file). This should allow the map to display properly.

2) There is a problem with rendering polylines on the map while running the app on a device with Android 5.0. The new native libraries (so files) should fix the bug and are available on the dev website page.

Answer (score 1):

I have got same problem with you. The demo code works find, but my own project don't show the map background. After trying by remove part by part from the demo code to find down what make the differences, I figure out that I need to insert the onResume function to my activity class.

So, please check your map activity if this code existing or not.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume(); // your SKMapSurfaceView instance
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the solution! Thanks quang! :)